# Problema con el plugin org.apache.maven.plugins

Tags: eclipse, maven

Estoy ejecutando un proyecto java mavenizado, y al ejecutarlo como maven build me salta un error relacionado con un plugin. El error es:

```
--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ Sesion05jmr779
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to 
C:\Users\jseme\Desktop\kernelPanic\Repositorio\Sesion05jmr779\target\classes
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.242 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-02T13:00:25+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/164M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler- 
plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project Sesion05jmr779: Fatal 
error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
```

A continuación muestro los tres plugins que tengo en el pom.xml

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <formats>
                    <format>html</format>
                    <format>xml</format>
                </formats>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>Sample.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>9</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

¿Cómo soluciono el error de consola?

Comment: Solo para confirmar ¿Estás corriendo Maven con el JDK 9?

Comment: Si, estoy ejecutandolo con el JDK 9